# get variable outside curly braces in Ruby

Tags: ruby, variables, scope

I have this code:

```
def foo( condy )
   ['<','>'].each{ | char| 
      ret = condy.split( char ).reject{ |x| x.empty?() }
      break if ret.length > 2
   }
   return ret
end
```

This code errors out, because ret is not recognized
However, this code does work:

```
def foo( condy )
   ret = []
   ['<','>'].each{ | char| 
      ret = condy.split( char ).reject{ |x| x.empty?() }
      break if ret.length > 2
   }
   return ret
end
```

My question is simple:
How does one get the ret variable to persist outside the curly braces, w/o defining it first outside it. It's nit-picking, I know.

Comment: Is it really duplicate?  Here you could use each_with_object, but the original question is using loop, where you don't have that option.

Answer (score -1):

Unless you declare it outside of the function, it's not possible to return it after the fact. As soon as you escape the braces, the variable goes out of scope, and is therefore unusable. Not a Ruby developer, but I know this is the case In other languages.